# What does "Target UID3" mean when creating a new Symbian application in Qt Creator?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, symbian

This appears in one of the steps of the New Project wizard in Qt Creator, when creating a new Symbian application.

It says **Target UID3: 0xE3491AB7**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short:

> A UID is a globally unique identifier consisting of a 32-bit number.
>   UIDs are used throughout the Symbian platform to enable various kinds
>   of file identification and association.
>
> Because UIDs are fundamental to the Symbian platform, it is important
>   that they are used correctly when developing programs. To ensure
>   uniqueness, it is essential that UIDs are properly allocated.
>   Uniqueness is guaranteed by allocating UIDs centrally from a database
>   managed by Symbian at https://www.symbiansigned.com.

And:

> During development, or for test code, temporary UIDs may be chosen
>   from the unprotected test range 0xExxxxxxx. These UIDs can be used
>   during development for unsigned applications but must not be used in
>   released software. Note that such applications may not be installable
>   via a SIS file. See the Symbian Signed website for more information.
>
> Care must still be taken to avoid clashes within development teams and
>   between multiple projects, including old projects which may still be
>   installed on an emulator or native platforms. UID clashes may stop a
>   program from loading correctly, typically leading to Not Found errors.

For a comprehensive description about UIDs see the relevant page in [Symbian Developer's Library](http://library.developer.nokia.com/index.jsp?topic=/S60_5th_Edition_Cpp_Developers_Library/GUID-35228542-8C95-4849-A73F-2B4F082F0C44/sdk/doc_source/ToolsAndUtilities94/Build-ref/Mmp-ref/uid.html).